# What is the neurobiological basis of Spearman general factor of intelligence?

Tags: neuroscience, reference-request, intelligence, cognitive-neuroscience

I found a brief intro to the genetic factor of human intelligence: ["Biology of human intelligence" by J A Böök (1976)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1036362/).

Also it is known that gyrus hipocampii is basis of STM which have role in general factor.
What I can't find is how the biology of the brain is connected to IQ measurement.

What is neurobiology, physiology and anatomy basis of human intelligence in general?

Edit: is there any revue article which summarizes neurobiology, physiology and anatomy basis of human intelligence in general?

The book "[Behavior Genetics Principles: Perspectives in Development, Personality, and Psychopathology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1591470838)", edited by Lisabeth F Dilalla (American Psychological Association, 2004), explains the genetic basis of personality. I am looking for a similar book or article which summarizes the physiological and anatomical basis of intelligence.

Comment: Connected to IQ *measurement*, or connected to *IQ*? Connected to IQ: processing speed, neural networking density etc. relate to what the brain can or cannot do. How should the brain *not* be related to intelligence? The general factor *is* the brain's basic potency.

Comment: i mean absolutely what you mentioned. biology to IQ to IQ measurement. I know that there are several concepts IQ from Spearman to Guilford to Gardner, but I am interested if there are any research which will connect spearman works to biology. if there are some other research related to guilford or gardner i will also like to read that.

Comment: also i think there are some reserch where IQ was measured directly by EEG, not by paper and pencil

Comment: imo, intelligence is an ill-defined term.  I think it would take volumes to answer the question as is.  Narrowing it down might be productive.

Comment: [Intelligence is ill-defined](http://egtheory.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/economic-turing-test/) in the sense you are using it in, and the [genetic correlate of general fitness or mutation load](http://www.wiringthebrain.com/2012/07/genetics-of-stupidity.html).

Comment: inteligence is defined as is, there is evidence in EEG and findings in hypocampus related to IQ. I am looking for more evidences or research. if it exists.

Comment: For computer scientist who deals with inteligent systems human inteligence is ill defined. But I am not looking for clarification. I am looking for physiology basis of spearman general factor. Hm, i will narrow my question, thank you. ;)